# Rode NT-USB microphone has poor audio quality after upgrading to Windows 10 18.09 (october update)

Tags: windows, audio, recording

ever since I installed the latest version of Windows 10 (18.09 october update) my Rode NT-USB mic yields very poor recordings.

What I tried so far:

- Use different audio recording softwares (Audacity, Windows audio
  recorder, etc.): Same poor quality with all these.
- Installing the same Windows version on another pc and try the same
  mic: Same problems.
- Reinstalling the os: no succes.
- Google the problem: Found only old posts that were somewhat similar
  but had no applicable solutions.
- Search for drivers from Rode website: None available.
- Try recording with the mic on something other than Windows 10 18.09:
  Good quality.
- Try recording with another mic (Logitech Webcam C920): Also poor quality
  (although I have no actual "good quality" reference with this
  device).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in Advance

Markus

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. 
My fix was to look in the control panel, Hardware and Sound, Sound, Recording devices, advanced.
RODE-NT was only in 2ch, 16bit, 8000 Hz
Changed it to 2ch, 16bit, 48000Hz = Perfect recording

Tested it, and changed it to another USB port. Then the device reverted back to low settings.